# javascript time format convertion using regular expression

Tags: php, javascript, regex

AM using regular expression to check the given time in the format **HH:MM**

eg.,

```
var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)\s*$/;
    if ((m = s.match(re))) {

result = (m[1].length == 2 ? "" : "0") + m[1] + ":" + m[2];
        }
```

Which works fine.But i want to convert and display the given number to the given regular expression format .Can any one help me in finding solution for this.

Example :

> if we enter 1 it has to convert as 01:00 or 1.0 as 01:00

Or is there any other way to convert other than regular expression

Comment: Does not the IF-statement always evaluate to true?

Comment: If u use some library like date.js, you can output or parse in any format you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
format2 = function(n) { n = parseInt(n, 10); return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n }

time = "1"
p = (time + ":0").split(":")
formattedTime = format2(p[0]) + ":" + format2(p[1]);
```

This converts all possible numeric inputs to the HH:MM format